# Как определить ошибку исполнения функции?

Tags: c, linux

Вызов функции sysconf возвращает ошибку.

```
int pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);

if (pagesize == -1) {
    // Обработать ошибку
}
```

Как выяснить ее причину?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Функция `sysconf`, как и многие другие функции C, устанавливает код ошибки в переменную `errno`. Получить строковое значение кода ошибки можно с помощью функции `strerror`.

```
// Распечатать ошибку
printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
```

Это поможет определить причину.

Comment: или perror() пишет в stdrerr.